# Is it better in terms of speed to use variable instead of redeclaring jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

While working, I am often using same nodes as a selectors for jQuery objects, like    `$('.often')`    As I suppose, jQuery every time composes a new object for it, but I can also assign already made object to variable:    `often=$('.often')`    Apart of possibly better readability would the use of same object as variable increase the script's performance?

Comment: Depends, in most cases caching selectors makes sense, to use once or twice, it's not really neccessary

Comment: Not only does it build a new object, it also has to actively query the DOM!

Comment: Write a test: http://jsperf.com/

Comment: `would the use of same object as variable increase the script's performance` If you need to wrap it anyway, then Yes. If it is a noticeable gain depends on the scenario. However, don't wrap if you don't need to, i:e if all you want is accessing a native element attribute like `value` or `href` then don't bother wrapping a `$()` around it as that is then adding the minimalistic overhead : `on('click', function(){this.value ; this.href, etc..// not need to wrap});`

Comment: "possible duplicate of jQuery - Is it okay to use $('#ElementId') everytime?" Yes, that question fully adresses my interest, sorry I have searched but have not used caching or cache word and I have missed it, should I delete a question? To think, when searching in search engines I am very often find duplicates, not the original questions, just because I am using different keywords, so maybe there is a way to just link this to first question?

Comment: @epascarello [Here you are](http://jsperf.com/jquery-object-recreation)

Comment: @still_learning thank you, very visually informative

Comment: Thinking about this, if element with class I am used to create a jQuery object will be removed from page, or new element of the same class will be added, the object inside variable will not be updated and this may lead to errors?

Comment: Your question gave no context for the variable. Yes, if you cache it long term, and the DOM updates, then your object will not be updated. If you're talking about within a single function call where there are no such updates, then there'll be no issue.

Comment: @Blue Skies Thanks for reply, its just minor thought related to question, thought better just ask it in comments, instead modifying question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a function with the same parameters twice is a code smell... in any language.

A function's implementation is usually a detail with which the function's caller isn't concerned, but the caller can usually safely assume that calling the function twice is more expensive than assigning its return value to a local variable.

Unless the function behaves differently depending on state (for example, in a multi-threaded application), just call it once.

This may be more a matter of style than technique, but if I was to see something like this:

```
if (get_my_value("param") == 1) {
    return "Got 1.";
}
if (get_my_value("param") == 2) {
    return "Got 2.";
}
```

I would rewrite it to:

```
var my_value = get_my_value("param");
if (my_value == 1) {
    return "Got 1.";
}
if (my_value == 2) {
    return "Got 2.";
}
```

The reasons I would rewrite it are:

1. If `get_my_value` is expensive, I've improved performance.
2. By reducing code duplication, I've improved maintainability.
3. By reducing code duplication, I've improved readability.

Comment: +1 but you've got a couple extra closing parens in your second code block.

Answer (score 2):

I would say typically, yes, it is worth caching the object in a variable. However, performance is not necessarily my reason for doing so.

As a convention, you will find many javascript/jQuery devs prefix variables which refer to jquery objects with a `$`, eg

```
var $myObject = $('#id');
```

The reason to do so is that you now know later on that there is no need to wrap that variable again, ie it avoids this mistake:

```
var myObject = $('#id');
... much later on out of sight of that declaration
var myJQueryObject = $(myObject); // No need for this, but its a common mistake.
```

Comment: I don't understand. Your reason for using a variable is so that you can have a variable that starts with `$`? I mean that may be desired if you already have a variable, but it's not much of a reason to cache it in the first place.

Comment: @Blue Skies As I am understand, $ is used only to remember that it is a variable that holds a jQuery object, not some other javascript entity, like DOM node, so you will not mistakenly wrap it into jQuery object again.

Comment: @Dmay: Right. I'm saying that the reason given in this answer for caching the variable doesn't make sense. There may be reasons to label certain variables with `$`, but that presumes that it has already been decided that a variable was needed. You're asking if a variable is needed in the first place. Putting `$` at the beginning of a variable name doesn't have anything to do with the decision to use a variable in your circumstance.